# Display table-cell on nested element?

Tags: css

Is it possible to apply table-cell to a nested element?

In the code below ive applied display table to the ul. To keep my code clean (there are a number of override to consider in my actual code, the example below is simplified) it would be best if I could target the links directly and forget about the list items. Is this possible?

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>

ul {  
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

/* This works when uncommented
li {
  display: table-cell;
}
*/

/* This doesnt work */
a {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

http://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: What do you expect to have happen with the `display-table-cell` on the anchor?

Comment: Short answer no - it would mean that it would be a table cell in it's own right rather than as part of the ul "table"

Comment: Of course you could dispense with the `ul/li` completely and just wrap the `a` tags in a `nav` tag...that would work.

Comment: May be **DOM STRUCTURE** because of structure `<ul>` as a table then `<li>` first children so they are table-cell. if you remove all `<li></li>` and works with `<ul><a></a></ul>` then you can give `table-cell` to `<a>` tag. its work exactly the same way as `<li>`.

Comment: @Atal Shrivastava Unfortunately, you can't do that as the only permitted **direct** children of a `ul` are `li`.

Comment: but the same can be tried with `<div>` or `<nav>` @Paulie_D

Comment: sorry for repetition, same thing you have already told in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buuilding on @Pete comment that it would mean that the `a` would be a table cell in it's own right rather than as part of the ul "table"

Of course you could dispense with the `ul/li` completely and just wrap the `a` tags in a `nav` (or `div`) tag...that would work.

[**Jsfiddle Demo of both methods**](http://jsfiddle.net/NdVeb/5/)

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul,nav {  
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}


li {
    display: table-cell; /* method 1 */
}

nav a {
    display: table-cell;  /* method 2 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {  
  display: table;
 width: 100%;
 }

li {
  display: table-row;
}

 a {
  display: table-cell;
  }
```